# upside down question mark and question mark in Tex or MathJax

Tags: support, mathjax

Years ago, I read a story where a one-line conjecture in a serious mathematics paper was interpreted as a theorem by some incautious reader. Some embarrassment ensued. The suggestion was that, especially for one-line conjectures, one could put an upside down question mark before and a question mark after; I think this is ordinary usage in written Spanish. Note that this is sometimes done in *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory* by Richard K. Guy; I'm looking at section A8 on prime gaps, and it is a question on prime gaps that I just answered...

Can someone please tell me how to do this within a displayed equation, meaning double dollar signs before and after? I tried looking at the MathJax website. It would not surprise me if this were available in more recent Latex than the book I own indicates, in which case I would love to know the Latex method.

Will

Answer (score 5):

A general approach is via the `\unicode` command ([see here in the MathJax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.1-latest/tex.html#unicode-support)). Google informs me that the Unicode number for the upside-down question mark is `191`, and indeed, `$\unicode{191}$` produces $$\unicode{191}$$

[Further Googling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark#Fullwidth_question_mark) leads me to the unicode `FF1F` for the "fullwidth question mark" $$\unicode{xFF1F}$$
which appears to be a good match stylistically ([at least, as I'm seeing it on my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpeDt.png)).

---

My current font doesn't seem to have unicode `2E2E` in it; the command `$\unicode{x2E2E}$` just appears as a box to me.

However, the other reversed question mark `061F` works fine for me, and it also fits in stylistically, more or less: `$\unicode{x061F}$` produces $$\unicode{x061F}$$
[which appears on my computer like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2y2w.png).

Comment: So, Zev, is there a unicode question mark of matching size/font for the end of the equation/inequality?

Comment: I think I've found a good match. Answer edited.

Comment: The actual character displayed depends on a number of factors, going from your MathJax rendering mode, the fonts available, luck and the position of three of Saturn's moons.

Comment: FF1F, cool! How to do this: U+2E2E  ⸮   e2 b8 ae  REVERSED QUESTION MARK

Comment: For whatever reason, x2E2E works for me. It is just a guess that other people will see the same thing I see; anyway http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541727/a-conjecture-about-the-difference-between-consecutive-primes-with-respect-to-a-p  MEANWHILE x061F produced the right character but scrambled everything else in the inequality.

Comment: On a Mac, the keyboard shortcut for ¿ is Option+Shift+?

Answer (score 4):

You can copy them from here :-)

```
¿¿¿¿¿¿¡¡¡¡¡¡¡
```

For example, $¿1+1=2?$ is `$¿1+1=2?$`.

Comment: Aha! You allow me to do what I wish, while retaining your secrets!

Comment: Well, I have a Spanish keyboard, so in a way I am cheating.

Comment: I used it at the prime gap question. Better with spacing \; between that and the equation/inequality.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5p-uspcgRY

Comment: `\textquestiondown` and `\textexclamdown ` (from `textcmds.sty`) are somewhat more official ways to get these, but maybe they don't work here.

Comment: The \textquestiondown did not work, I can see that I spelled it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend the conversion of some unneeded key (a win-key is always good candidate) into a [compose key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key). You can just type [compose] + [?] + [?] then to produce the unicode character `¿`. Works in math mode, or wherever you like it.